# maven module based build

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

In maven pom.xml I have configured 4 modules

```
<modules>
    <module>tech-source</module>
    <module>tech-development</module>
    <module>tech-product</module>
    <module>tech-customers</module>
</modules>
```

the three modules containing sources and 4th module containing customers folders with assemblers, webapp assemblers and pom.xml files.

Project structure

```
src
  tech-source
  tech-development
  tech-product
  tech -cutomers
      CUSTOMERS1
      CUSTOMERS2
      POM.XML
```

I am using maven command to take build is **mvn clean install** , but this command taking build for both the customers.

I want to take a build customers1 should contain all the source code. (i.e)

```
    <module>tech-source</module>
    <module>tech-development</module>
    <module>tech-product</module>
```

this is mainly for time consumption. Waiting for suggestion, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try working with [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your parent pom.xml

```
<project>
...
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <modules>
                <module>tech-source</module>
                <module>tech-development</module>
                <module>tech-product</module>
                <module>tech-customers</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>customer1</id>
            <modules>
                <module>tech-source</module>
                <module>tech-development</module>
                <module>tech-product</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

After that if you run `mvn clean install` your default profile is going to run. And if you run `mvn clean install -P customer1` your customer1 profile is run.

Comment: But latest maven release profile is not possible it seems